# Looking For Help With SharePoint 2010 Workflow

Tags: workflow

I’m way behind schedule and need help with a list approval workflow in SharePoint 2010 or Designer.  I can use the “Approval – SharePoint 2010” to auto generate approval requests to our same three approvers (one at a time) for all requests, however, a fourth step is required as listed below.

1. Employee submits a training request form to SharePoint
2. Employee receives a confirmation email indicating initial receipt of the form.
3. The first approval request will be sent to the employee’s manager (manager’s email is included in the submitted form - field titled “Manager”)
4. Upon approval by the manager, the process would then proceed as if using a normal Approval – SharePoint 2010 process of approval.

In Designer, I created a workflow to send the manager an approval request using “Current Item:Manager” and “Current Item:Created By” to send the submitter an acknowledgement email.  I would rather do this in SharePoint as I don’t know how to develop Designer Workflows.

Can I use two workflows, one for the manager that would somehow trigger the standard “Approval – SharePoint 2010” workflow for the other three?  I tried using “Current Item:Manager” in the address field in SharePoint but that doesn’t work like in Designer.  Thank you.

I'm still having problems and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Below is what I have with steps 2 and 3 being the same and step 4 ending the process.

Step 1
Email Current Item:Created By

Then Start Approval process on Current Item with Current Item:Manager

Step 2
If Current Item:Aproval Status euals 0;#Approved

```
Start Approval process on Current Item with John Doe
```

Else if Current Item:Approved Status equals  1;#Rejected

```
Stop the workflow and log Approval was Rejected
```

Step 3
IF Current Item:Aproval Status euals 0;#Approved

```
Start Approval process on Current Item with John Smith
```

Else

```
If Current Item:Approved Status equals  1;#Rejected

Stop the workflow and log Approval was Rejected
```

Step 4
IF Current Item:Aproval Status euals 0;#Approved

```
Start Approval process on Current Item with Frank Crank
```

Else

```
If Current Item:Approved Status equals  1;#Rejected

Stop the workflow and log Approval
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this in SharePoint Designer. Your logic would be close to this:

```
Send email to [Current Item: Created By] #Receipt
Start Approval process for Manager #Initial Approval.
If Current Item:Approval Status equals Approved
 Start Approval process for Secondary Approval #Secondary Approval 
Else
 Stop Workflow and log Approval was Rejected
```

Comment: Okay, this is where I get a little Designer stupid.

Comment: This is a good article to teach you more about SPD workflows: http://plexhosted.com/billing/knowledgebase/226/How-to-create-a-simple-approval-workflow-in-SharePoint-Designer.html

Comment: Guess I'm not doing something right.  I created the workflow in designer and save it but it won't appear on SharePoint like the other workflows did.  I assume Sharepoint won't accept if there are errors??

Comment: Did you publish it? You also have to checkbox the "Allow workflow to be started manually" in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Yes, I had done all that.

Comment: Evidently it's publishing but to the wrong list. Not sure how to correct that.

Comment: In the article I linked, it will tell you how to choose the list of the workflow.